# how to put symbol on top of tensor product

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

How do I put a `$\frown$` right on top of `$\otimes$`? 
I tried `\stackrel` but it leaves too much space between symbols.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please show, how you try so far ...

Answer (score 7):

Here's a possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\frownotimes{\mathbin{\mathpalette\frown@otimes\relax}}
\newcommand{\frown@otimes}[2]{%
  \vbox{
    \ialign{##\cr
      \hidewidth$\m@th#1{}_\frown$\kern-\scriptspace\hidewidth\cr
      \noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern-1pt}
      $\m@th#1\otimes$\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\frownotimes B_{x\frownotimes y}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Where does `\hidewidth ` come from (`amsmath `)?

Comment: @daleif Plain TeX; it's essentially `\hskip-1000pt plus 1fill`

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\def\frownotimes{\mathbin{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{-1.4\LMpt}{%
  \SavedStyle\otimes}{\mkern1mu\SavedStyle_\frown}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}}}}
\begin{document}
$A \frownotimes B_{x \frownotimes y}$
\end{document}
```

[image]